# PHP Specific JSON Array nesting level Confusion

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was wondering if someone could help please. I have a JSON feed from an API, and I can never figure out the levels to get the information I need?

the JSON is below

```
{
  "sourceId": "1234",
  "sourceType": "MONITOR",
  "searchMeta": {
    "startTimestamp": 1462361513,
    "endTimestamp": 1462508560,
    "maxResults": 10000,
    "metricType": [
      "clients"
    ],
    "family": [
      "Product"
    ],
    "metricsInterval": "M5"
  },
  "clients": {
    "One": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1462361400,
        "avg": 2,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 3,
        "probes": 6,
        "samples": 3,
        "sources": [
          "123",
          "234",
          "345",
          "456",
          "567",
          "789"
        ]
      },
```

I was wanting to get the Probes value and the Samples value into a variable

```
foreach($json['clients'] as $range => $product){

echo $product['timestamp']." Probes: ".$product['probes']." Samples: ".$product['samples']." <br>";

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$product[...]` instead of `$range`?

Comment: Thanks, Sorry, I changed one and not the others. It will still not print the values though. I edited the main to correct the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you'll have a range of clients (*hence the loop*). So you'll need to loop each client too as it's an `array` of `object`'s.

If you visualise it, that looks like this:

```
CLIENTS = ARRAY(
    1 => ARRAY( OBJECT{} ), // you want the OBJECT{}
    ....etc
)
```

So the below loop will get it for you.

```
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($data['clients'] as $range => $product) {
    foreach($product as $element){
        echo $element['timestamp']." Probes: ".$element['probes']." Samples: ".$element['samples']." <br>";    
    }
}
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#V25UwF363)

Returns the following:

```
1462361400 Probes: 6 Samples: 3 <br>
```

Comment: Outstanding Darren. Thank you so much for this. and the explanation. A true legend!!!!!

Comment: My pleasure @RenegadeRob - just a lil tip for you too while dealing with `json`; check out jsoneditoronline.com - it'll help you understand how to loop and the structure and all! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**The demand of OP:**

> I was wanting to get the Probes value and the Samples value into a
>   variable

Simple just name your json file as `$json`.

```
$arr = json_decode($json);

echo $samples = $arr->clients->One[0]->samples; //3
echo $probes = $arr->clients->One[0]->probes; //6
```

Comment: There are many more, so I really would need it in a foreach though. About 300 fields

Comment: you are asking to get only two values. so i did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($data['clients'] as $client){

echo $client['timestamp']." Probes: ".$client['probes']." Samples: ".$client['samples']." <br>";

}
```